# Error loading xml document in WCF Library

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I am creating a wcf library that needs to read xml files as pass the elements through the service that will be using in my windows 8 app.

Question is I first created a WCF application using the same code and it worked fine but now using the library the xml files are returning as NULL.

```
  {

            var doc = XDocument.Load(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/TestCodes.xml"));
            var testCodes = doc.Descendants("TextInfo");
            return testCodes.Select(item => 
            {
                var xElement = item.Element("Value");
                var element = item.Element("Description");
                if (element != null) 
                    return xElement != null ? new TestCodes()
                    {
                        Value = xElement.Value,
                        Description = element.Value
                    } : null;
                return null;
            }).ToList(); 
        }
```

Is there another way to read in an xml files in a library that differs from the wcf application? Unfortunately I have to use the WCF Library so no way around that part.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Have you checked if the file exists at the path given?

Comment: @Yahya, yes it does. I didn't put in any folders or anything. I just left directly in the project. Worked fine in the application so that is why I am confused.

Comment: forget about loading in xml document for a moment. Try reading the file in a string and see what you get.

Comment: @Yahya, tried the following  'string test = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("TestCodes.xml");' and still didn't work

Comment: Did you check if you have HttpContext in that area?

Comment: yes the httpcontext does show up

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50791/discussion-between-yahya-and-csharpdev4evr)